# Combine rows of Bash "ps" by command

Tags: linux, bash

How to combine processes of the same program in Linux Bash when using `ps`, `top` or `htop`?

For example, when called `ps -eo pmem,pcpu,args` instead of this:

```
...
2.0  1.0  /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
3.0  2.0  /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
5.0  1.0  /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
2.5  1.0  /usr/sbin/mysqld
...
```

it would show

```
...
10.0  4.0  /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
 2.5  1.0  /usr/sbin/mysqld
...
```

with memory and CPU values summed.

Maybe there is another command to achieve this?

Comment: I suggest to take a look at `awk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{m=$1; c=$2; $1=$2=""; pmem[$0]+=m; pcpu[$0]+=c} END{for(i in pmem) {printf("%5.1f %5.1f %s\n",pmem[i], pcpu[i], substr(i,3))}}' file
```

Output:

```
 10.0   4.0 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
  2.5   1.0 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

With some comments:

```
awk '{m=$1; c=$2                # save column 1 and 2
     $1=$2=""                   # remove content of columns 1 and 2
     pmem[$0]+=m; pcpu[$0]+=c}  # save memory and cpu to hashes and
                                # add to its value, use rest of
                                # row as key

     # print content of both hashes and key in a loop
     END{for(i in pmem) {printf("%5.1f %5.1f %s\n",pmem[i], pcpu[i], substr(i,3))}}' file
```

Comment: Thank you. It works when I pipe in the previous command. However it's rather cumbersome, and if I wanted to see some other performance stats, I'd have to edit quite a few things. Shame there is no option to perform this seemingly mundane task within ps or top or htop. I'll probably have to save this as a script.